# What package does org.core.databinding belong?

Tags: eclipse, packages, requirements

One of my applications requires **org.eclipse.core.databinding** but I can't seem to a package to install that satisfies this requirement. Does anyone know how to find and install this (if it requires anything more than a using Install New Software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding_FAQ:

> Where can I get the plugins?
>   The JFace Data Binding plug-ins can be found in any of the following distributions on the Eclipse download page:
>
> - List item
> - Eclipse SDK
> - RCP Runtime/SDK
> - Platform Runtime/SDK
>     Just select the desired build (e.g. stable, integration, nightly) and download one of the above distributions.
>
> The plug-ins you need are org.eclipse.core.databinding, org.eclipse.jface.databinding (if your UI is implemented using SWT and JFace), and org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans (if your model objects conform to the JavaBeans specification).